# Как передать строку в запрос к БД

Tags: python, sqlite

Имеется функция:

```
def data_selection(): 
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE num = 5")
```

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы пользователь сам ввёл **num = 5** с клавиатуры и передать эту строку в запрос.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно провернуть что - то подобное?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
inp = input()
z = 'SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE num = ' + str(inp)
c.execute(z)
```

Comment: 1. [input()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#input) и так строку возвращает, поэтому `str(inp)` не нужен. 2. Так составлять sql через конкантенацию строки запроса не рекомендуется из-за sql-инъекций, например вместо `5` я напишу `1 or 1 = 1` и тогда `select` станет `SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE num = 1 or 1 = 1'` и вернет `все`. Правильно через параметры заполнять

Comment: Спасибо всем. Информацию про sql-инъекции учту.

Comment: про input спасибо, забылся. а про скуль-инъекции - как только в запрос нужно будет передавать что-то сложнее цифр - рекомендуемый Вами метод борьбы с ними перестанет быть таким уж действенным, а в строчном виде запрос и проще отладить, и можно логировать, ежели чего... это я не в качестве спора, уточнение.

Answer (score 4):

В соотсвествие с документацией для метода [execute](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) примерно так

```
num = int(input())
c.execute("SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE num=?", num)
```

либо:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE num=:num", {"num": num})
```

Comment: c.execute("SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE num=:num", {"num": num}) - это передача аргумента в функцию, я спрашивал про строку.